# Lightbox with wordpress magic fields. Multiple size image

Tags: php, wordpress, lightbox

Can anyone help me create a lightbox with wordpress magic fields.

I need one 'Image (Upload Media)' in magic fields to create 2 images in different sizes.

e.g a thumbnail 100 x 100 px

and a lightbox image 600 x 400px

wrapped in the code:

```
<a href=“http://localhost:8888/large-image.jpg” rel="lightbox"><img src=“http://localhost:8888/thumbnail-image.jpg” alt="" /></a>
```

I am a bit stuck on how this could be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution.

PHP backend (http://wiki.magicfields.org/doku.php?id=front-end_functions):

`echo '<a href="'.get_image('fieldName',1,1,1,NULL,"w=600&h=400&zc=c&q=90").'" rel="lightbox"><img src="'.get_image('fieldName',1,1,1,NULL,"w=100&h=100&zc=c&q=90").'" alt="" /></a>';`

JS frontend (http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

I suppose you use jQuery library for lightbox, so read about jQuery selectors.
Your situation: Attribute Equals Selector [name="value"]
Your js code must be:

`$("a [rel='lightbox']").lightBox(params here)`